# How to set a custom download path in Chromium in Truclient protocol of Loadrunner

Tags: performance, loadrunner, vugen, microfocus, truclient

I am trying to record a UI in Truclient protocol using its Chromium extension. As part of my workflow, I am downloading a file by clicking a button on UI. While replaying my script the downloaded file is saved in the default download path of Chrome. I can see the settings of Truclient Chromium browser where the path is editable. But as soon as the "develop" mode is exit, the path resets to the old default (which is also the default in system).

I want to control where my file should be saved after download on the load generator. Any advise is appreciated!
notes -

1. I am looking for solutions only specific to Chromium and not for IE or Truclient Browser as my UI is only compatible with Chrome.
2. LR version - 12.6x

Answer (score 0):

Currently as I known, TruClient still do not support customize the download path in Chromium. You could try to switch to TruClientBrowser which is based on Firefox.

1. Open TruClientBrowser
2. Navigate to about:config
3. Add key value as:
   [image]
4. Replay and save your script before close the browser
5. Reopen the script and test the download path again

Comment: Thanks Erxin. I am aware of this setting for TruClientBrowser. I guess there is no solution for Chromium at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

TC Chrome uses the default download path.

For Windows, this is usually:
`C:\userName\Downloads`
and can be changed using

Ctrl+E (Open File Explorer) -> Right Click on Downloads -> Click Location -> Change the Path

[image]